# How to merge two objects based on id and group same key value pairs

Tags: javascript

```
      var routePlan = [
      {
        "id" : 1,
        "farmerName" : "Farmer1",
        "farmerId" : 1
      },
      {
        "id" : 2,
        "farmerName" : "Farmer2",
        "farmerId" : 2
      },
      {
        "id" : 1,
        "farmerName" : "Farmer3",
        "farmerId" : 3
      }
    ];
```

I want to merge objects having same id and create a new combined object using javascript or angularjs

```
      var routePlan = [
      {
        "id" : 1,
        "farmers" : [
          {
            "farmerName" : "Farmer1",
            "farmerId" : 1
          },
          {
            "farmerName" : "Farmer3",
            "farmerId" : 3
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id" : 2,
        "farmerName" : "Farmer3",
        "farmerId" : 2
      }
    ];
```

Please help me, I have seen lot of examples on the net but nothing seems to match my requirement

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question shows no sign of effort. It is a requirement and not a problem statement.

Comment: Your data structure should be consistent. That is decide if an `id` can have multiple entries or not - and it looks like you have decide that. So, `farmers` should always be an array even if there are no entries, a single entry or multiple. That will save you a huge headache.

Comment: I know its a requirement, but I have tried lot of things using code from already answered questions, nothing seems to work, I dont know how to show my effort in stackoverflow, i am not an expert in javascript, i need help or just guidance

Comment: data comes from api response, i am unable to create empty farmers object

Comment: @user3327684 Please include a small, clear, sample of the raw data from the API, what you want as the final result and what you have tried and failed at to get that final result. Be sure to include any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can surely be improved, but this is a working solution:

```
let temp = routePlan.reduce(function(acc, item){
    acc[item.id] = acc[item.id] || [];
    acc[item.id].push({ "farmerName": item.farmerName, "farmerId" : item.farmerId });
    return acc;
}, {});

let newRoute = Object.keys(temp).map(function(key){ 
    let newObj = {}

    if (temp[key].length > 1){
        newObj.id = parseInt(key);
        newObj.farmers = temp[key];
    }
    else
    {
        newObj = Object.assign({}, routePlan.find(elem => elem.id == key));
    }

    return newObj;
});
```

Note the `reduce` function used to group your objects by `id`.

Comment: Thanks Marco, great help

Answer (score 0):

You could take a hash table as reference to the groups.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, farmerName: "Farmer1", farmerId: 1 }, { id: 2, farmerName: "Farmer2", farmerId: 2 }, { id: 1, farmerName: "Farmer3", farmerId: 3 }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    grouped = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        function getP(o) {
            return ['farmerName', 'farmerId'].reduce(function (r, k) {
                r[k] = o[k];
                return r;
            }, {});
        }
        if (!(a.id in hash)) {
            hash[a.id] = r.push(a) - 1;
            return r;
        }
        if (!r[hash[a.id]].farmers) {
            r[hash[a.id]] = { id: a.id, farmers: [getP(r[hash[a.id]])] };
        }
        r[hash[a.id]].farmers.push(getP(a));
        return r
    }, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```